# How to volume control certain system sounds and notifications in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, notifications

Since upgrading to windows 10 I've noticed that some application no longer turn up in the Volume Mixer, and I'm unable to configure their notification sounds/volume like I was able to in Windows 7.

How can I configure these? I don't want to disable notification sounds entirely, for all applications, I just want to be able to volume control them.

Vuze as an example, creates a notification whenever a torrent finishes downloading. I still want the notification, and the sounds,  but without it being max-volume and waking the whole family up.

Answer (score 0):

[It seems this isn't possible](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-notification-sound-volume-adjust/9d553bb2-105d-4b46-bc91-fb20a0c6369f) :(

The best solution seems to be to create your own .wav file to replace the one in use with a quieter version.

How to find/change the .wav file: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/turn-off-change-windows-10-notification-sounds/

Comment: I couldn't post more than 2 links, so here is a link to changing the .wav to be quieter:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sjsd0MzCk-M